# Animation of Sprite not updating physics

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

Im using Level Helper and SpriteHelper to create my sprites, images, levels and more importantly animations and physics.

Note, by physics i mean the debugdraw you can see on the simulator that is used for collision detection.

I created a swimmer and added physics to this. Done the code so the physics follows the swimmer around the pool as they move. I have now come to animate the swimmer, make the legs kick etc. Now when i load my game and only the first sprite of the animation is the outline for the physics. So i can see the legs kicking on the swimmer but the debugdraw mesh of the physics doesn't animate as well. Now this is not really a problem until for example my swimmer loses their legs (weird game i know). I change the animation to now a swimmer with no legs but again the physics mesh still shows the legs. So any collisions with stuff still happens where the legs were but they shouldnt. This make sense?

Is there a way to update the physics on the new animation or do i need to remove my whole swimmer and draw a new one?

Any help at all would be great. Thanks

Comment: On the box2d side, do you have separate meshes for the swimmer's legs ? You should remove them/ detach them from the rest of the body

Comment: Hi, no i just have the one mesh of the first sprite of the full swimmer animation at the start.

Comment: ok, then on cocos2d side, what do you do to "cut his legs" ? update with another animation that has no legs drawn? Or Do you have separate children sprites for the legs?

Comment: I have two sets of sprites which make up two different animations. I run the one animation with the legs, then switch animations to the other one with no legs (as you know, the physics mesh for the first animation (first sprite) stays there).

Answer (score 0):

This makes sense, since your sprite uses the same box2d mesh in both states. If you want to have a different collision behavior after altering your Sprite, you should assign another (smaller) mesh body.

Note that even in cocos2d side, your sprite still has the same container box with the new animation.

In order to keep using the SpriteHelper functionality you might want to create 2 different sprite-body sets: one with the full body, then after the "accident" replace it with the legless sprite.

Now, gameplay-wise, my opinion is that there shouldn't be any collision for the legs anyway. since they are moving, players will not find it weird to have them not colliding. You could use a mesh body with no legs and use it for both sprites. Except if you want to have different collisions as a gameplay feature (Like giving the player the choice to cut his legs in order to fit in a smaller cave etc)